# Tikzposter - Stretching the title box to accommodate a long title

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, titles, tikzposter, parbox

I have a long title for my tikzposter, which I want to keep all on one line for the sake of the poster's spacing.

What I have now is this:

```
\centering
\settitle{
\parbox{\linewidth}{
    \centering \color{titlefgcolor} {\bfseries \Huge \centering \mbox{Towards Scalable Multi-Robot Systems by Partitioning the Task Domain} \par}
    \vspace*{1em}
    {\LARGE \@author \par} \vspace*{1em} {\Large \@institute}
    }    
}
```

Which gives something like this:

[image]

If I remove the `\mbox`, the line is broken, which makes the title box too big. Rather, I want the title box to stretch and re-centre to accommodate the long title, like so (mocked up in inkscape):

[image]

How can I modify `\settitle` to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\maketitle[width=0.875\textwidth]`

Comment: @koleygr perfect! That worked. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome.. happy TeXing!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by @koleygrs's suggestion of using `\maketitle[width=0.7\textwidth]`